# Hosts file being reset after every reboot

Tags: macos, vpn, hosts

My `/private/etc/hosts` file is being reset after every reboot. I can make my changes, save the file, and it will work. Right up until I reboot my Mac. Has anyone found a work around for this or a way to prevent it from happening?

I'm running OSX Yosemite 10.10.4.

UPDATE: It was my VPN Client, Cisco AnyConnect. See comments for solution.

Comment: hmmm. it should not do that. What is it rewritten to (the original?) do you use the "Cisco AnyConnect "

Comment: Buscar, you are correct. I am using the Cisco AnyConnect. I just noticed my file was reset about ten minutes ago, and connected it to my VPN software. Now to figure out why.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue with this link: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20111011050950471 Buscar, Why don't you post this and the any connect info as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices.

One is stop using Cisco AnyConnect -not a solution just a choice.

The other is just use the Cisco AnyConnect host file and modify it with your modifications, since it will will overwrite your /private/etc/host.

Cisco host file:
    /private/etc/hosts.ac